# Running untrusted user code in a web page

Tags: php

I have been tasked with creating a website that will be able to run users code and display the output or errors. The problem I can foresee is major security risks from allowing users to run languages like c++, java, c, c#. Has anyone had some experience in doing this. I would like to run the code in a sandbox environment but i don't know if this is possible using just php alone. Would rewriting my entire framework over to node be better?

Answer (score 0):

> ... but i don't know if this is possible using just php alone. Would rewriting my entire framework over to node be better?

Makes no difference either way.  You're still going to have to appropriately sandbox the runtime you're executing.